# find the last 5 lines, in each text file in a folder, that contain a matching pattern

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I am a Unix Newbie and have been trying to get around this one task for quite some time now.
Would be great if someone could help me.

Problem - I need to loop through a folder, into each .txt file and then fetch the last 5 lines that have a specific word (ex : test)

I am trying to traverse through the folder, into each file, and print the last 5 lines where the word 'test' has occured.

for example - if the word 'test' is found in line numbers 1,3,5,7,9,12,14,15.
then I need to only print the whole line at line number 7,9,12,14,15.(i.e the last 5 lines that have the occurrence of this word)

I am somehow not being able to upload images in my question but I hope this info helps:
File 1 - [Here there are 7 occurances of the word test and I need just the last 5]
File 2 - [Here there are 6 occurances of the word test and I need just the last 5]

The command I figured out is :
cd to folder path:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -iH "test" {} + | tail -n5; tail -n0 | grep -i test
```

This command works but it prints the last 5 lines and then exits.
It does not go into another file.(since it already has found its last 5 lines with the matching word)

In my case, however I want the output to be the last 5 lines of 'each' file.

Can someone please help. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't see your attachments and you should give the info inside your question anyway.

Comment: Do you look for files where each of the last five lines contains the specific word? Or text files where at least one of the last five lines contains it?

Comment: Hello Yunnosch.
Thank you for your reply.
I am trying to find last 5 lines from EOF where the word has occured.

for example - if the word 'test' is found in line numbers 1,3,5,7,9,12,14,15. then I need to only print the whole line at line number 7,9,12,14,15.(i.e the last 5 lines that have the occurrence of this word)

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

You can't use a pipe in the exec part of the find command. As a workaround you start a shell inside the exec part which takes a command which now can include a pipe.

To let the new started shell know where the command starts and ends, simply use single quotes.

> I need to loop through a folder, into each .txt

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

> where the word 'test' has occured.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep "test" {} \;
```

> and print the last 5 lines

OK, here we need to start another shell inside the exec part of find:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'grep "test" {} | tail -n5 ' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNIX tools you could:

```
tac file | grep -m5 PATTERN
```

To combine this with `find` you need to exec a shell because of the pipe between tac and grep:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'tac "${1}" | grep -m5 PATTERN' -- {} \;
```

Comment: `grep -m` stops after 5 matches. I think OP wants to stop after 5 lines, but OP has not answered this my question-comment yet.

Comment: Well, the OP says *and then fetch the last 5 lines that have a specific word (ex : test)*. That makes me think that `grep -m5` is appropriate.

Comment: Ah, I think you are right, it matches part of OP coding attempt: grep, then tail -n5. Still, too much guessing needed for my taste. But not your fault, you have a good answer to a plausible guess what the question is.

Comment: Hello hek2mgl.
I tried your command but unfortunately I do not have tac in my system.
Would be great if you could help me out with an Sed/Awk/Tail command

Comment: You can install it. It belongs to GNU coreutils. Otherwise the answer from @Klaus should work.